# Git and client/server code separation

Tags: git

You are building a software with separated client and server-side code (different people) - would you create one repository or two?

E.g., we have front-end developers who are not working with server code, so they are not interested in checking it out. A server-side developer doesn't change client-side code too, but he is responsible for building/deploying the whole application. What is best practice?

Comment: I like the separation more because I can easily see if there any changes in 'my' code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set it up as separate repositories and use submodules to import them into a big main repository that can be used to synchronize and test. Any shared code can be created in a library project (another repo). Might seem like an overkill for a smaller project but as the code base starts to grow it will prove quite useful.

Answer (score 6):

I would generally keep the two parts in one repository. They will be much easier to keep in sync that way. And, they may even share code or some sort of protocol specification file.

The presence of extra files for each developer shouldn't bother them too much. If this is really an issue, then there are ways to tell Git to not populate certain directories when checking out code.