# Separation of code and environment in pinax while using git

Tags: python, git, layout, code-organization, pinax

I have a somewhat large project written in django and pinax. Currently I keep then entire virtualenv and my source tree in the same git repository; however, this is becoming very unwieldy I would like to keep the environment separate from the source code as frankly it is becoming very hard to manage. I have only found [Git and client/server code separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266709/git-and-client-server-code-separation) which doesn't apply to me, since my question is about separating the environment from the source. Is there a specific way, directory layout, to use with virtualenv that can keep the environment separate? For example

```
./env
./src
```

Currently the default for virtualenv is to have

```
./env
./env/project/
```

Currently I use the second layout, and have all the env and source in a single git repository, this is what I need to change.

The problem with the first layout is that path's don't work and modules raise ImportError. This might seem like a cosmetic issue, but is very annoying to me. What is the procedure for separating virtualenv from the source code while using git.

Comment: You definitely want to keep source code and environment separate and there is no problem doing this with Pinax. If you've pip-installed all your requirements into the virtual env, I'm not sure why you'd have any ImportErrors.

Somewhat secondarily, why do you need to put the virtualenv in git?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the env in git, as you found out it's not designed to be portable - it's designed to be ephemeral and repopulated whenever you transfer the project to another machine or location. Try creating a fresh env at the new location and `pip install -r requirements.txt` again. I hope you've been keeping your requirements.txt up to date :)

Comment: See also https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html#making-environments-relocatable